# alpha channel WHITE in animation

Tags: animation, transparency

I have 100 pngs images having a transparent background, and I need to render them in an animation - mp4-h264.
I did that in blender but the default background color for the rendering is black, while I need it white, and I'm not able to find anywhere an option for changing the alpha channel (there is the option if I want to render just an image, but not the whole animation).

Any tips?

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you are making the animation in the Video Sequence Editor so you could add a white strip in the background.

1. <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> → `Effect strip` → `Color`.
2. In its properties (<kbd>n</kbd>) go to `Effect strip` section an change the `Color` to white.
3. Render again.

Maybe you need to select the `Alpha Over` mode in `Blend` option of the strip with your image sequence so it uses their alpha channel.